# order of operation

Tags: arithmetic

For the following expressions,why we can get the right answer even we do addition /subtraction first ?

- $3+4\times 11-5 = (3+4)\times(11-5) = 42$
- $6+4\times7-4$
- $5+2\times13-10$
- $4+7\times16-6$
- $3-2\times1+5$

Comment: The simple answer is "because they were designed that way"...

Answer (score 1):

Expressed algebraically, you have:

$$\begin{align}
a+bc+d&=(a+b)(c+d)\\
a+bc+d&=ac+ad+bc+bd\\
a+d-ac-ad-bd&=0\\
a(1-c-d)+d(1-b)&=0\\
\end{align}$$

This is a single simultaneous equation in 4 unknowns, therefore it has an infinite number of solutions - you have just found some of them.

Rewriting to address OP comment

$$a=\frac{d(b-1)}{1-c-d}$$

Pick any integers $c$ and $d$. Choose integer $b$ such that $a$ is an integer.